# Why can't I register multiple Django ModelAdmin with same Model?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I have the following ModelAdmin:

```
class EventAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # ModelAdmin config

    def queryset(self, request):
        queryset = super(EventAdmin, self).queryset(request)
        return queryset.exclude(date_end__lt=date.today())

admin.site.register(Event, EventAdmin)
```

Now I want to add a model to manage archived (older than today) events.

```
class EventArchiveAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # ModelAdmin config

    def queryset(self, request):
        queryset = super(EventArchiveAdmin, self).queryset(request)
        return queryset.filter(date_end__lt=date.today())

admin.site.register(Event, EventArchiveAdmin)
```

But if I try to do so I get *AlreadyRegistered* exception.

Why can't I implement another ModelAdmin with same Model and how can I get different *admin views* of the same model?

I know I can implement a custom `list_filter` in my class but I'd like to keep things separated in different pages.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use proxy models:

```
class Event(db.Model):
     ...

class ActiveEventManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(ActiveEventManager, self).get_queryset().filter(active=True)

class ActiveEvent(Event):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True

    objects = ActiveEventManager()

class ArchiveEventManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(ArchiveEventManager, self).get_queryset().filter(active=False)


class ArchiveEvent(Event):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True

    objects = ArchiveEventManager()
```

Now, you can register 2 models without override `ModelAdmin.queryset` method:

```
class EventAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # ModelAdmin config

admin.site.register(ActiveEvent, EventAdmin)
admin.site.register(ArchiveEvent, EventAdmin)
```

You can read mode about [proxy models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/models/#proxy-models) and [managers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/managers/#modifying-initial-manager-querysets) in the doc.

Also, use this:

```
queryset = super(EventArchiveAdmin, self).queryset(request)
```

As first argument `super()` take *current* class. See [doc](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#super)

**Note:** django has renamed `Manager.get_query_set` to `Manager.get_queryset` in django==1.7.