# Django custom adminsite index page apps link to default adminsite

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I've created a custom admin site thus:

```
class M3Admin(AdminSite):
    pass

m3admin = M3Admin(name='m3admin', app_name='m3admin')
```

I'm registering models with both the default admin and custom admin thus:

```
class FooAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Foo
    pass
admin.site.register(Foo, FooAdmin)

class FooM3Admin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Foo
    pass
m3admin.register(Foo, FooM3Admin)
```

I've registered the custom admin app and setup urls.py thus:

```
url(r'^m3admin/', include(m3admin.urls)),
```

When I go to the custom admin, m3admin, I get the expected list view showing the model Foo.

However, the clicking Foo or add or change takes me to the default admin NOT the custom m3admin!  What do I need to do differently?

Comment: This link is about your issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12790220/why-cant-i-register-multiple-django-modeladmin-with-same-model

Comment: Proxy models are certainly useful for registering a model multiple times in an admin and customizing the admin differently for the original and proxy model.  The issue here is different though.  The model IS being registered properly on the custom adminsite but within the custom adminsite the CRUD links are pointing to the default adminsite.